# as.POSIXlt vs as.date and strptime

Tags: r, plot

Basically, I have this date set for electric consumption per min in a household and I have a data with 9 columns, my data is:

https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Individual+household+electric+power+consumption

so I tried two things and got two somewhat different output and I cant seem to figure out why is that:

first input:

```
hpc$Datetime<-as.POSIXlt(hpc$Datetime, format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

with(hpc,plot(Datetime,Global.active.power, ylab = "Global.active.power(Killowatts)", 
     xlab = "",type = "l"))
```

[image]

second input:

```
hpc<-read.table("hpc.txt", skip = 66637,  nrow = 2879, sep =";")

hpc$Time<-strptime(hpc$Time, format = "%H:%M:%S")

hpc$Date<-as.Date(hpc$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y")

with(hpc,plot(Time,Global.active.power, ylab = "Global.active.power(Killowatts)", 
     xlab = "",type = "l"))
```

[image]

Why is there a line appearing in the second image
It will be a great if someone can be kind enough to help me out!!
Thankyou in advance

Comment: In the second example you are just plotting `Time` on the x axis, which covers several days, so it will be trying to fit all days on one graph (I guess this is not what you want). The line is probably caused by the end of one day being followed in your data by the first point of the next.

Comment: Your `1st` graph looks correct to me. Just investigate why `tick` on `x-axis` shown as `day of week`. Is `hpc$Datetime` is correct?

Comment: @AndrewGustar thanx, I kind of got what your trying to say.

Comment: @MKR hpc$Datetime is correct infact the 1st graph is correct or I should, it is what I was expected to do in my assignment so by combining date and time I got days of week in those ticks and I am also wondering how that happen. anyways thanx!!